# Formula (text) field on prechat form for live Agent

Tags: formula-field, liveagent, pre-chat, embedded-services

I am setting up prechat form on salesforce live agent and couldn't find any date fields. I have created a text formula field and it is not on available list of fields while configuring prechat form.  I am trying to place date of birth field on our prechat form which is on Lead object and having issues. Does prechat form allows only text and number fields ? I am not planning to create any custom component. Is there any workaround using Embedded service deployment code sinppet.

Comment: formula field by definition is read-only. Why would you want to put that in a pre-chat? Please elaborate on your usecase. Thanks

Comment: Prechat forms are meant for collecting information. The DOB-related conversations should be handled by the Bot instead.

Comment: @Swetha we are prepopulating all these fields on Pre chat form and not collecting any information but need DOB for matching purpose. we had to remove DOB from matching criteria to fix it for now.